# How to stop sending input form data to SQL database on browser refresh?

Tags: php

On every browser refresh old data that have already been sent to database are sending again.
I want to insert data in database if the input name 'title' have some value.

This is my html form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td><p>Title: <input type="text" name="title"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><p>Comment: <input type="text" name="comment" class="inputtext"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>  
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"value="16000000">
<input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile"> 
</td>
<td width="80"><input name="upload"type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload "></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('','','') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('db', $con);
if(isset($_POST['upload'])&&$_POST['title']>0)
{
$title = $_POST['title'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
$fileType=(get_magic_quotes_gpc()==0 ? mysql_real_escape_string(
$_FILES['userfile']['type']) : mysql_real_escape_string(
stripslashes ($_FILES['userfile'])));
$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

if($db){
   $query = "INSERT INTO table (title,comment, name, size, type, content ) ".
 "VALUES ('$title','$comment','$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
mysql_close();
echo "<br>Success: $title <br>";
}else { echo "Error"; }
 } 
?>
```

Comment: you don't want the values to resend on refresh you are saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you do whatever you need with the submitted data, you can make a redirect to the same page, for example:

```
header('Location: /yourpage/');
exit;
```

If anyone tries refreshing that, it will just refresh to content but the form won't be submitted.

If you need to display an error message or a success confirmation, you can just save it in session parameters and `unset` them when the message is shown.

`exit` is needed so that the script doesn't continue to execute and send data to clients who chose to ignore the header.

**"Headers already sent" error**

If any content has been output before the `header()` call, you'll get a `headers already sent` error. If PHP has any content to send to the browser, it automatically finishes the headers and starts outputting page content. At that point no additional headers can be set. This can be caused by anything outputting content, e.g., `print`, `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` and other functions, or perhaps HTML code or even whitespace outside `<?php .. ?>` tags.

To avoid this you can either:

1. Structure your code so that all of the PHP code is executed in the beginning, before any content is output.
2. Use output buffering so that PHP collects all content and outputs it only at the end of the script. You can read more about it (including about other ways to access the content) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), but the simplest way is to just put `ob_start()` somewhere near the beginning of your script, before any HTML code or content output.

Comment: Thanks, but all I get is warning message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent....

Comment: Right, that can happen if there has been any output before the PHP script. I'll update the answer to clarify about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would query the database with the values give first so you can make sure you are not entering a duplicate entry (which you'll want to check anyways..)
and just return if any entries are returned.

```
if($db){
$checkQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE TITLE = $title AND COMMENT = $comment"
$result = mysql_query($checkQuery) or die('Error, query failed'); 
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { return; }

$query = "INSERT INTO table (title,comment, name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$title','$comment','$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
mysql_close();
echo "<br>Success: $title <br>";
}else { echo "Error"; }
}
```

If you don't want to do this you can use a post, then redirect, then get pattern: [explanation](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)

Comment: I am getting markdowns for this advice.  Is there something wrong with this advice?

Answer (score 0):

reset the form using JavaScript reset() on window load.

```
window.onload=function(){ 
var frm=document.getElementsByTagName(form);
frm.reset();
};
```